# Visual Studio 2022 - Debug .NET 6/7 Background Service with Runas a Different User

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2022, runas

I need to execute a .NET 6 or 7 Background Service as a different account user.  Note I need to do this in **Visual Studio 2022**.  I have referenced ["Start external program" functionality under the Debug section of a project's properties](https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-launch-different-user/) and reviewed [How to debug a Visual Studio 2022 console application running as a service using a gMSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087060/how-to-debug-a-visual-studio-2022-console-application-running-as-a-service-using/).

Has anyone figured out how to do this with 2022's new Debug settings?

I've tried different permutations on the following screen, with different arguments, with and without working directory, etc.:

[image]

When I debug the application, a console appears requesting the password (I do realize there is switch for caching this) which I provide.  It attempts to start a different console, yet closes extremely quick.  The original console then shows an exit code of 0:

[image]

VS's Output window shows the following:

```
08:12:35:002    The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
08:12:35:002    The program '[33484] runas.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
08:12:35:002    The program '[33484] runas.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

My TargetFramework is "net6.0" and I have a number of runtimes and sdks on this box.

Has anyone been successful with 2022 and have some recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure if [RunAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) works on your OS. Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923052) shift + right-click method

Comment: This is Window 10 so yes it does.  If I attempt to run VS as the service account then it struggles with licensing and source control.